# What requirements are needed to replace an attic fan control switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, attic, fans

I have an emerson high speed fan switch in one of our houses.   It is just a a knob that controls the fan speed.     I would like to replace it with a different color one and one that includes a timer.   Are there any requirements for attic fans vs regular fans?    For example could I connect a regular timer switch that I would use for an exhaust fan?

The switch is labeled as compatible with fans WHF 1124, WHF 1130, WH 24WS,WH 30FM, WH 30 WS, WH 24FS, WH 30FS, WH 24FM

PN 1414 0064 000

I am being a bit obtuse in not just replacing with a replacement model because I am curious what my options really are.    Just playing with the fan (yes I didn't RTFM) it seems that I have to let it run at full power for a certain amount of time to start it up properly then I can adjust the speed.    So guessing your tradition (even 20A) timer switch wouldn't work unless it would be going full speed all the time.

Comment: Power requirements should match.  And no rentals(you own both and only your family stays there/winter, summer/vacation homes)

Comment: how many wires go from switch to the fan ? Is it PWM type

Comment: If you have the part number from the old one we can probably figure out what replacements work for it.

Comment: @isherwood - redone many many a house.   Installed attic fans but always used the switch kit that came with them.    So I googled it, and no clear answer so I asked it.    Yea I can figure it out but better if someone adds expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally there are two types of fan controllers:

- Old fashioned, which have multiple wires from switch to the fan connecting to appropriate motor coils
- The PWM type using single wire to the motor and using PWM to control the speed

Comment: It seems like a basic knob switch but has some bulk to it.   It appears to be black coming and going connected, hence why I asked the question...  other than handling 20A why does there need to be a special speed control for an attic fan.

Comment: @DMoore speed control is optional, while fancy would be speed control based on attic temperature. Timer would be optional but welcome, you do not want it run all the time